# Eclipse debugger is jumping to the wrong return statement

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I've run into a really weird situation. I'm doing the following in Java (through Eclipse Galileo) on the Android 2.1 platform:

```
// Get gravity & geomagnetic data to return to the caller.
final int SIZE_GRAVITY = 3, SIZE_GEOMAGNETIC = 3;
final float[] NOT_USED = null;
float[] outGravity = new float[SIZE_GRAVITY];
float[] outGeomagnetic = new float[SIZE_GEOMAGNETIC];
final String NO_DATA_COULD_BE_READ = null;
boolean succeeded = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(NOT_USED, NOT_USED, outGravity, outGeomagnetic);
if (!succeeded)
{
    return NO_DATA_COULD_BE_READ;
}

Log.v("Test", "This should be printed - but it isn't!!");

// Prepare the data to return.
final int X = 0, Y = 1, Z = 2;
final String FIELD_SEPARATOR = ",", VECTOR_SEPARATOR = ";";
String returnValue = "" +
    outGravity[X] + FIELD_SEPARATOR +
    outGravity[Y] + FIELD_SEPARATOR +
    outGravity[Z] + VECTOR_SEPARATOR + 
    outGeomagnetic[X] + FIELD_SEPARATOR +
    outGeomagnetic[Y] + FIELD_SEPARATOR +
    outGeomagnetic[Z];

// Return data.
return returnValue;
```

When `SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(...)` returns `false`, the Eclipse debugger shows that the if-statement that says `if (!succeeded)` suddenly jumps to `return returnValue;`. No exception is thrown and LogCat - even on verbose mode - receives no unusual message. It doesn't even receive the message I put in the code. I tried the obvious clean-and-restart-Eclipse approach and that didn't help. I'm very confused.

The Eclipse debugger is telling me that the second `return` statement is being called. However, putting additional print statements in shows that the first `return` statement is actually the one being reached. Perhaps I've stumbled across an Eclipse bug? Or anyone could explain this anomaly?

Comment: Kind of threw me when I first saw that behavior in eclipse but it at times seems to jump to the bottom of a method if a return statement higher up is executed, mostly just an annoying visual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you sure that it jumps to the last `return`? You have a `return` in the if, this is most likely this one which is called.

Comment: "How are you sure that it jumps to the last return?" Good question; I'm surprised I didn't ask myself that sooner. A print statement was placed and showed that it was indeed the first if statement being called - despite Eclipse showing clearly that it was the second. Perhaps this is an issue with Eclipse?

Comment: See [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg31467.html). It seems that this is due to some optimization during the conversion Java bytecode → Dalvik bytecode which merge the two `return`.

Comment: That's probably it. Thank you!

Comment: Just for future questions: return statements are not CALLED, methods (or in other languages, functions, procedures, subroutines or even "scripts" get called). A return statement is EXECUTED, and a variable is not called either, but "referenced" or read or set.

Comment: Point taken. I should probably get my terminology straight if I'm going to be in this industry :D

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `succeeded` is false. Debugging will make it look like the method jumps to the bottom `return` when you do any `return`. Put a log before

```
  return NO_DATA_COULD_BE_READ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess, you are in misconception. The control is not reaching the last `return` statement because the earlier `return` statement is getting executed.

```
 return NO_DATA_COULD_BE_READ;
```

Since `succeeded` is turning out to be `false` (as you said), the if-condition is satisfied and then it simply returns the `null` value of the `NO_DATA_COULD_BE_READ` string, which is inside the if-condition block.

So, `Log.v("Test", "This should be printed - but it isn't!!");` is never reached as per observation.