# Java code is jumping over return statement

Tags: java, return, try-catch, bufferedreader

I've got a try/catch loop and this is the last section:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    String jsonResponse = reader.readLine();

    Log.d("BSARD",jsonResponse);

    return jsonResponse;
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("BSARD","Something weird happened");
}
return null;
```

When I run in debugger, it performs everything right up to the "`Log.d("BSARD",jsonResponse)`" but jumps straight to "`return Null`". I've checked that jsonResponse is a valid string - hence why I put the Log.d statement in there so I could pause the code and check the variables. If I add more code in after the "`Log.d("BSARD",jsonResponse)`" line it executes those fine - it just never does the "`return jsonResponse`".

I'm totally stumped. I have no idea why it is doing this as I have an identical piece of code in another java class that is performing fine.

I've tried cleaning the build and rebuilding the project a few times but to no avail. I've also modified the code to move the null return into the catch loop and put an additional statement in front of it and it still jumps to the null without executing any of the catch code in front. There is nothing in the stacktrace and no exception is actually thrown.

So regardless of whether the null resides in or outside the catch statement - it jumps directly to it.

Here's how the code looks currently....

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(u);
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    String jsonResponse = reader.readLine();
    Log.d("BSARD",jsonResponse);
    return jsonResponse;
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.d("BSARD","Something weird happened");
    return null;
}
```

Any clues?

Comment: Did you try to clean the project ? Project > Clean.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: Does it jump to `return null`, or to the closing bracket of the method? A debugger may jump to the closing bracket to indicate that it's leaving the method, regardless of where the return statement that was executed is.

Comment: Try adding `System.out.println("got here");` before both return statements (make the text different so you know which it reached) and see which line gets output. If neither does, then your code isn't recompiling for some reason. Otherwise it should give you a clue as to what is happening.

Comment: you might not be building up the project, try building it again.

Comment: cleaned and rebuilt several times. new code added, stuff moved around - still fails and jumps to "return null"

Comment: @DaveBanthorpe what's in the log, any exceptions there?

Comment: nothing there that I can see

Comment: what is weird is that it is jumping to the "return null" regardless of whether it is inside or outside of the catch statement - so the catch is not firing so no exceptions .

Comment: Does `Log.d(BSARD, jsonResponse)` output the contents of `jsonResponse`, and if so, what is the complete line output?

Comment: Yes it does - this is the value seen in Logcat:    {"statusCode":200,"data":{"id":918592,"team_id":54,"member_id":32110,"date":"2015-05-02T13:25:00.000Z","enddate":"2015-05-02T14:25:00.000Z","type":"off","notes":"","parent_id":null,"repeat_every":null,"repeat_until":null},"meta":{}}

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean project and server!!! It could might be possible that your code is not build properly.

Comment: I'm curious as to how the code couldn't be built properly and produce these results? Is your theory that he's running a version of the code compiled with the first return statement removed?

Comment: @Edd It could be running an earlier version where there was no return, or an exception occured.

Comment: @Alex That was the only possible explanation I could think of. If an exception occurred, the corresponding log line would have been printed.

Answer (score 0):

How about this - what does the calling method get back?
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671456/eclipse-debugger-is-jumping-to-the-wrong-return-statement) suggests this could be a compiler optimization which is merging the two return statements, in which case it would appear to the debugger that the "return null" statement is executed, but the caller would actually receive your JSON.

Java allows the compiler to make changes to optimize your code, provided this does not change its runtime behaviour.